# How to get column that have the same value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

Sorry for my lack of knowledge in MySQL but how do you get the same value in different field?

For example if i have a table like so :

```
+-----+-----+-----+   
| id  |  A  |  B  |
+=====+=====+=====+   
|  1  |  1  |  2  |     
|  2  |  3  |  1  | 
+-----+-----+-----+
```

And i would like to get the value 1 from A and B.

I tried doing something like :

```
SELECT A, B FROM table_name WHERE A = 1 AND B = 1
```

But this won't return a value if somehow A or B doesn't have the value 1. In cases like that I want it to only return the value 1 from the column that does have it. I want something like this :

```
SELECT A, B FROM table_name WHERE value = 1
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: It is often helpful to say what you want as a sentence. In this case: "I want all the rows where the value of 'a' OR 'b' are equal to 1." That would be your hint that you needed to use "OR". In your failing example, you were telling the database that you "want all rows where both 'a' AND 'b' were equal to 1". (Note: this does NOT always work, but when you are starting out it can help.)

Comment: Two rows is rarely going to be enough to communicate the desired outcome, no matter how straightforward. See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry So sorry didn't mean to make it hard for people to understand my questions, I'll take that as a note if I want to question anymore SQL related questions. But I got my answers

Comment: Questions and answers both have the opportunity to serve the broader SO community - rather than just the OP - so it's never too late to improve your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `OR`:

```
SELECT A, B
FROM t
WHERE A = 1 OR B = 1
```

This can be shortened using `IN`:

```
WHERE 1 IN (A, B)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I want

Answer (score 1):

You should use query as:

```
SELECT A, B FROM table_name WHERE A = 1 OR B = 1
```

Here, you get rows which have either A=1 or B=1 or both A & B = 1.